# ASP.NET append QueryString once it is has a specific value

Tags: asp.net, mobile, query-string

I have a mobile website and a normal website. On a mobile device it detects on the normal website that is a mobile device and redirects to the mobile website.
I can also go back from the mobile website to the normal website by adding the querystring:
no_redirect=true

This way the JS won't execute the mobile detection code again.

I have this only for my homepage (mobile detection), so when i navigate to other pages in my normal website the QueryString isn't present anymore. Once i go back to the homepage i will be redirected to the mobile site again (no QueryString, so mobile detection kicks in).

Sample URL on mobile website to normal site: 
http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?no_redirect=true

I am looking for a way to add the QueryString no_redirect=true to all pages once it's set/present. This only happens when i navigate back from my mobile website to the standard website. This will avoid that i need to go back and forth from mobile to normal everytime i visit the homepage.

Someone any ideas or solutions for this.

Thx in advance

Comment: Maybe just use a cookie too?

Comment: By the way it could be either solved by JS/jQuery or VB/C#. Whatever would work best. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for quick replies! But i got it to work like this.

Maybe people were wondering why i only have the mobile detection on the homepage? This i because it's a responsive website, but initially i want to show the mobile site because it loads very fast on 3G. Of course when someone enters on another URL it will just show the responsive website right away.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

If Request.QueryString("no_redirect") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("no_redirect").ToString()) Then
Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("no_redirect")
    cookie.Value = Request.QueryString("no_redirect").ToString()
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
Else
    If Request.Cookies("no_redirect") IsNot Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("/default.aspx?no_redirect=true")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a seperate master page for the homepage (default.aspx) only of course otherwise this would mess up things!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with asp.net, why not use the features IIS provides?

There is a Url Rewrite module available for the IIS, which is a perfect fot for this kind of situation.

Whether you want to append your variable to the url, it's up to you, mut I would highly recommend against it, since people tend to bookmark urls and share these bookmarks also. The possibility that someone initially shares a link which gets used on a different kind of device, are quite large and leads to bad user experience.

There already is a question in stackoverflow which remedies the issue you're facing.

[IIS URL Rewrite rule for mobile with "nomobile" cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182287/iis-url-rewrite-rule-for-mobile-with-nomobile-cookie)

The processing of the rules take place on the server BEFORE the request is passed to the ASP.NET pipeline, which means you don't need to load any page 'initially' and then redirect. Which is quite the opposite to the solution you're currently proposing.

See the question I linked, and if you really wish to append the querystring, simply change the appendQueryString property to true on your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Session variable for this instead of trying to modify every link.  however, here's some jquery that might help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function(i,o) {
        var href = $(o).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf('?') > 0) href = href + '&no_redirect=true';
        else href = href + '?no_redirect=true';
        $(o).attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cEKeK/